# Concourse CI - Build results

Tags: build, continuous-integration, concourse

I've not been able to find any way in Concourse to show a 'build summary page' as you get in Jenkins/TFS etc. In those tools you can see build history (OK/failures), build durations, unit test results, code coverage, various graphs etc - but Concourse just has build history which is simple log files.

There doesn't seem to be any extensions system or other way to achieve this.

I'd prefer to use Concourse for the pipelines and build-in-containers approach, but it's a hard sell to developers who see it as a step backwards.

Thanks
Paul

Answer (score 4):

The containers/workers of your plan/build are spinned up and spinned down. Everything you want to keep you need to PUT to a resource. In the concourse ecosystem there are many resources created.

The results and output logs of your builds/jobs are by default available in concourse UI (ok/not-ok, time). See for example: https://ci.concourse-ci.org/teams/main/pipelines/main/jobs/build-fly/builds/1273 In the job itself you can expand and see the logs, so output log of your unit tests for example.

If you want to keep the sonar report you just install a resource like https://github.com/cathive/concourse-sonarqube-resource and you can simply run this after your unit test by using the PUT (and store it on your Sonar server). So indeed you have no html report you can keep on that specific build, but you can put it everywhere you need it to be by using/creating a plugin. Very simple and nicer because the whole Sonar overview of your project is where it belongs :)

Comment: OK thanks - I guess this is a different way of doing things to other CI systems!

Comment: "Very simple and nicer" Simple yes, but I'm not sure it's nicer having to first look up a build number/link from a concourse log, then manually open it in a separate tool.

Comment: It just depends on your workflow. The Sonar reports are also injected in every PR. So most of the times we don't even look in Concourse. Only when errors are thrown, but they some type of them are in our slack channel with correct links. So its all about flows, concourse is just helping every team to make their own perfect pipeline.